# Detecting user hardware through a website (server)

Tags: javascript, java, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to build a live-streaming web application. I am using a Java FFmpeg wrapper and using it to stream my webcam feed live to AWS MediaLive, which channels to MediaPackage to transcode and send the feed back to the website. However, while this would work locally, I will eventually have to host this application on something like AWS EC2, and detect a user's webcam and audio through the server (with FFmpeg being installed on the EC2 instance).

How can I do this? Services like Discord ask permission for the audio device on the browser and access it. How do websites like Discord achieve this?